# Collectionview cell with both direction

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have collectionview with horizontal flowlayout direction and size of a UICollectionviewcell is screen size. Is it possible to scroll vertical if content of cell exceeds the screen size height?

Comment: Have you tried putting the `UICollectionView` in a `UIScrollView`?

Comment: Anything is possible, what have you tried?  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Comment: @WilliamAnderson - No william. I achieved by using pageviewcontroller. Using scrollview is better idea, I will try

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I think, iPhone Youtube app is created in the same fashion!! :)

You can create a CollectionView controller with its collection view set to horizontal scrolling, set the collectionView cell size to the screen size. And set the paging enabled property of collection view to 
true.

THis will allow you to scroll horizontally as if each cell was a page itself.

Next up, you can add another collection view to each of these cells, with vertical scrolling property of this collection view.

THis can be achieved very easily by subClassing UICollectionViewCell of the CollectionViewController. In the subclass, each cell must have a UICollectionView property.

Remember that the UICollectionView in each cell will have to have delegate and datasource set up properly.

[This is exactly what you are looking for.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxIAT7f-yh8)

Source of all information is within this link just above. Hope this helps